# Is it OK to make private member public by defining my own PRIVATE macro in unit test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I do need to test a C++ class's private member method.

Since it's private method and I don't want to change it to protected, I cannot make it public by creating a subclass and adding using declaration.

So if I define a macro PRIVATE to replace private keyword. Is it a good way to solve this problem?

```
#if __UNITTEST__
#define PRIVATE public
#else 
#define PRIVATE private
#endif

class A {
    PRIVATE:
        void f();
};
```

Comment: What are you testing? For example Qt provides a find_child method which you can use to gain access to private GUI elements.

Comment: I think it should be fine... But why do you want that? This is a weird code. use system defined keyword. That will be more unstandable for the new comers. Anyways try your luck, to me it should work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using macros to change the meaning of a C++ keyword is an extremely bad idea. Not only does it confuse your readers, but it also opens up your code to compile-time abuses from well-meaning consumers of your code, who could make private members of your class visible to them simply by defining a preprocessor symbol.

The idea of unit testing private member-functions is equally harmful, because your unit tests break encapsulation of your implementation.

One should unit test only public and protected members. Private members, on the other hand, should be tested indirectly by calling public and protected member functions, letting private member functions remain implementation details that they are.

If you absolutely must test the private function (which I strongly recommend against), you could declare your unit test class a `friend` of the class being tested, granting its member functions access to private member functions of the desired class.